# Battery status like implementation using Swing

Tags: java, swing, custom-controls

I want to create icon which will show some status like load of the database, battery status (same as windows laptop battery icon) etc. On mouse over it should show exact percentage in tool-tip and it should change the icon depending on range of percentage, eg. if below 15% red coloured icon.

Is there any ready made implementation available for this?
Or any idea how can I do this ?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to create icon which will show some status like load of the
>   database, battery status (same as windows laptop battery icon) etc. On
>   mouse over it should show exact percentage in tooltip and it should
>   change the icon depending on range of percentage, eg. if below 15% red
>   coloured icon. Is there any ready made implementation available for
>   this? Or any idea how can I do this ?

- [JProgressBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) with changed [Background or Foregroung](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html)

Comment: This answer only partially answers the question.  JProgressBar doesn't have built in support for detecting the battery status.